# How to hide Confluent CLI tooltip

Tags: command-line-interface, confluent-platform

This is new, the tool tip to auto complete commands was a good to have but it doesn't even allow me to see the output of the command just entered.

I typed environment list but can't even see the list anymore
[image: tooltip hiding output]

Tried searching on how to hide this to no avail.
What is this called anyway? tool tip? helper?

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's the interactive shell, I can use the commands without it once I exit out of the shell